# How to describe Goldberg polyhedra using "chess knight moves"

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polyhedra

> Other forms [of [Goldberg polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron)] can be described by taking a **chess knight move** from one pentagon to the next: first take $m$ steps in one direction, then turn $60^\circ$ to the left and take $n$ steps. Such a polyhedron is denoted $GP(m,n)$.

I'm trying to convert this to octahedral Goldberg polyhedra, having squares and hexagons. So I would start from a square. But what are steps?

Do they mean $m$ chess knight moves? On a spherical chess board build out of squares and hexagons?  Shall I turn by $90^\circ$ if I jump to another square? 
Turn left or right?...

$\hskip1.9in$ Sorry, I don't play chess that way...

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: $GP_{IV}(m,n)$ : start from a square, walk $m$ steps (first step leaves the square and enter into a hexagon, remaining $m-1$ steps leave an hexagon on the edge opposite to one you enter and enter into next hexagon (or square, if this is the last step and $n = 0$). If $n > 0$, you are in an hexagon, rotate either left or right for $60^\circ$ and walks $n$ steps. It is easier if one have a polyhedron one can play with. here is [$GP_{IV}(2,2)$](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10ctO) and [$GP_{IV}(3,3)$](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10tktO).

Comment: So the idea, in the $n=2$ and $m=2$ case, is that we take two steps, turn, then take another two steps...and we're again at a square face?  In retrospect, I think I did a good job avoiding the OP's question entirely, but hopefully it's not entirely useless for OP.

Comment: I'd love it if it turned out this "chess" description gave you a way of viewing Goldberg polyhedra as quotients of some kind of grid, but looking at the pictures on the Wiki, I think the $GP(m, n)$ nomenclature really helps describe the polyhedra *after they've been created*. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: I agree @pjs36.  Of particular concern, it seems $GP(m,n)$ probably does not exist for *any* pair $m,n$.  In the octahedral setting, can we even have $n \neq m$?  Can we know what pairs are valid before creating the shape?

Comment: @KajHansen not 100% sure but I think [wC](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=K10wC) is $GP_{IV}(2,1)$.

Comment: I think you're right @achillehui

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rules are the same as in the icosahedral case: start from a square and look for the shortest path to another square, using a "chess knight" move. That is: go ahead for $n$ hexagons, turn left by 60° and go on for other $m$ hexagons. This polyhedron is then labeled $(n,m)$.

This polyhedron below, for instance, is labeled $(4,0)$, because if you start from a square and go ahead, after four steps you arrive at the nearest square:

[image]

This other polyhedron is labeled $(2,2)$, because to get to the nearest square you must first go ahead two hexagons, then turn left (or right) by one side (60°) and go straight on for two more hexagons:

[image]